# How to create historical data set for current and previous records

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a regular table in the SQL Server database as the below

| Name | Status | Modified Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| X | Fail | 16/09/2021 |
| X | Fail | 28/09/2021 |
| X | Done | 02/10/2021 |
| Y | Fail | 30/09/2021 |
| Y | Done | 02/10/2021 |

And I'm looking to make a report as a historical report based on the group of data as the below result

| Name | Current Status | Previous status | Modified Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| X | Done | Fail | 02/10/2021 |
| X | Fail | Fail | 28/09/2021 |
| Y | Done | Fail | 02/10/2021 |

any help will be highly appreciated

Comment: You can use the LAG window function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select * from (
   select * , LAG(Status) over (partition by Name order by ModifiedDate) prvstatus
   from table
) t where t.prvstatus is not null;
```

Comment: I already tried the same query but it's caused duplicate data when you need to read data from multi-table

Comment: @Marc,  I expect it to produce exactly the output specified in the question. If it doesn't help ask another question with the real problem.

Comment: @Serg in order to clarify the exact issue I have, I already added the above tables and the answer is never matched

Comment: @Marc - given your sample data this query produces **exactly** what you said you want for output. It seems that you must have a more complicated issue than what you posted which is why this isn't working for your real data.